# Index gets created but not printed

Tags: memoir, indexing

I have been working on a document since June and every time I compile it, a nice index gets created. Yesterday I added some more content (a new section to my chapter) and all of a sudden the index does not get printed anymore.

I use the `memoir` class, put `\makeindex` in the preamble, and `\printindex` at the end of the document.
In *main.log* I cand find these lines:

```
\main@idxfile=\write6
\openout6 = `main.idx'.


Writing index file main.idx
\@quotelevel=\count524
\@quotereset=\count525
(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.
```

I know you all want minimal working examples but I haven't changed anything to my preamble since three days.
Even when I remove all content and just put `hello world\index{haha}` you can see *main.idx* containing

```
\indexentry{haha|hyperpage}{1}
```

but not getting printed.

Can anyone provide tips on how to troubleshoot this? I would expect there are some clues in *main.log* but alas, no such luck.

Comment: latex just writes the source file for an unsorted index, you then need to run `makeindex` to generate the index in  `main.ind` , which latex will then include automatically

Comment: Am I really this stupid? ```pdflatex``` always reminds you to run ```biblatex``` but I guess it does not do this for ```makeindex```.

Comment: it probabaly says `No file main.ind` somewhere in your log